# Changing the sign of numeric values in a column

Tags: excel, vba, formula, numeric, multiplication

I have data in column D.

There is a header in column D1 and numeric values in D2 downward. I would like to select all numeric values in column D (the number of values is unknown) and multiply them by -1 (replacing the current values in column D). How would I do this through VBA code?

If I could use formulas in Excel I would simply drag the formula D2*-1 downward; however, I need the VBA equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works almost instantaneously when tested with 100,000 random values:

```
Sub MultColDbyOne()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, A As Variant
    n = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    A = Range(Cells(2, "D"), Cells(n, "D")).Value
    For i = LBound(A) To UBound(A)
        A(i, 1) = -A(i, 1)
    Next i
    Range(Cells(2, "D"), Cells(n, "D")).Value = A
End Sub
```

The sub works by first determining the last row with data in column D, then transferring it to a VBA array (which is, somewhat annoyingly, a 2-dimensional array with only 1 column), looping through that array replacing each number in it by its negative, then transferring it back. This `Range` to `array` then back to `Range` strategy is fairly common (and fairly efficient) in VBA.

Answer (score 2):

Just for curiosity I wanted to employ selecting special cells (numbers) feature of Excel. I created another function and tested the speed against the [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989841/changing-the-sign-of-numeric-values-in-a-column#33989968) created by [@John Coleman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996248/john-coleman).

If column D contains 10,000 values, [@John Coleman's function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989841/changing-the-sign-of-numeric-values-in-a-column#33989968) is faster.
If column D contains 1,000,000 values, this function is faster.

```
Sub ChangeSignColD()
    Dim v, x As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    x = Selection.Address
    With Cells(1, 5)
        v = .Value
        .Value = -1
        .Copy
        Columns("D:D").SpecialCells(2, 1).PasteSpecial -4163, 4
        .Value = v
    End With
    Range(x).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = 0
End Sub
```

In addition, I noticed that this function would not error if there was e.g. some *text* value in the column.

Comment: Interesting. I confess that I don't completely understand how it works.

Comment: You enter "-1" in some cell, copy it, then select D column, Home > Find & Select > Go To... > Special... > Constants, Numbers. And then Pasting with multiplying option. Those numbers in the function are not self-explanatory, this is why it might be harder to understand.

Comment: Clever. Also -- I like how you arrange it so that the net result doesn't move the selection.

Answer (score 1):

I like how @Zygd solve it, but i propose to use a cell for the `-1` not interfering with existing working range.

```
Sub InvertNumericSign()
    Dim LastCell As Range
    Dim SignRng  As Range

    Set LastCell = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
    Set SignRng = Selection

    If Not LastCell = "" Then Set LastCell = LastCell(2, 2)
    LastCell = -1
    LastCell.Copy
    SignRng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlMultiply
    LastCell.ClearContents
End Sub
```